# ListView has correct number of rows, but shows no text

Tags: android, listview, cursor, listactivity

I have created a ListActivity inside a tabhost, and this tab is supposed to show all records from a sql table. When I click the tab however, **it shows the right amount of rows** (separation lines) but there's no data/text anything else to be seen. So basically I get an empty list, and I've checked the database file, the data is there!

My table only has the columns _id and name.

This is the code I'm using:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Cursor c;
    ShowAdapter sa = new ShowAdapter(this);

    sa.open();
    c = sa.getSubscribedShows();

    String[] from = new String[] { "name" };
    int to[] = new int[] { R.id.text1 };
    SimpleCursorAdapter shows = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.show_list, c, from, to);

    setListAdapter(shows);
    sa.close();
}
```

And my other method simply returns the cursor:

```
public Cursor getSubscribedShows(){
    Cursor c = db.query(true, "shows", null, null, null, null, null, "name", null);
    c.moveToFirst();
    return c;
}
```

And my XML is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:id="@+id/text1" >
</TextView>
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: post the layout file for: R.layout.show_list

Comment: Just posted it, it only contains a textview though, and the id should be right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the `layout_height` propery to:

```
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

and see if that fixes it

Comment: My query method isn't the problem, maybe it's an older version or something, but the line I'm using is also used in the notepad tutorial on the android dev site (I had previously tried with the parameters you suggested, it had the same effect). But the `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` line fixed the problem. I don't understand why though, I have been using the same XML file in another activity and it worked fine there. Any idea why so? Thanks for your help!

Comment: great to hear it solved your problem. The reason it fixed it is because you were defining the layout to be fill_parent which will fill the entire layout's height with the textview.. which can be problematic. by wrapping it you wrap each row to that height, and that height is your text height.

Dont forget to mark my answer :D

Glad I could help.